# Parsing using preg_match

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match

I have the following code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $check = $_POST['theemail'];
    if (preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $check)){ 

    echo 'Email is valid ';
    }  

    }

        <form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off"> 


    <p align="right">Email <BR><input type="text" name="theemail" size="20" /></p>
    <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" /></p>
    <p align="right"><a href="index.php">register</a></p>

   </form>
```

This code checks if an email is in a valid format (name@host.com) when a user submits a form, and it works; my problem is, is that when I try to get certain contents from the preg_match to be echoed to the user when submitting the form.

For example: the user has submitted the following e-mail: john@gmail.com

I'd like that the user will see in return:
echo' Hello john(instead of john it'll be a variable $, or something that will display it). Your email's host is: gmail.com(instead of gmail it'll be a variable $ or something that will display it).

I tried to create divs around certain spots in my code in order to display them later in an echo, but i didnt succeed. Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Once you know it's a valid email address, it might be easier to just explode on @.  Also, it is likely a different pattern than yours, but filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL might simplify things.

Comment: Look at the documentation for preg_match, specifically, the 3rd parameter "matches" which you can pass in.  Also, look up regular expression "capture groups".  http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: 1) Exploding the "@" won't help me because I am trying to create something much complicated later on the same principle, but I need to start from here to get the basics. 2) I looked at the "capture groups" thingy, but I can't manage to warp the groups around certain spots in my code without getting an error.

Comment: You might want to use preg_match_all() so you can see all the groups returned by the regular expression engine...  If explode('@'...) won't help you, then you may have a problem that is not in evidence from the question.  Please tell us more!

Comment: Explode @ won't help me because I am later on planning to work with more groups, which have nothing to do with this email format, and I need to be able to control each group in order to be able to make them into a couple of varaibles in an echo. Is there a way to divide my preg_match code into a few divs/groups in order to display them in an echo?

Comment: Sure!  Each group pattern is wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Well, I know that, but how do I display each group sepreately? I need to pick only a few groups that the user has entered, and then have it displayed it to him as an echo (look at the code I gave above please.)

Comment: @user1938653, once you add that third param to `preg_match`, do a `var_dump` on it to see what's inside.  That should tell you what the next step is.  Also, please reconsider that regex, it's rejecting a large number of valid addresses.  It really is going to be easier to simply split on the last `@` and go from there after using `filter_var`'s validation method.

Comment: var_dump only shows me the content that the user has entered... how can I use it to break it down into groups? in my original code, ive successfully created an email format validator (name@hotmail.com), but I just need to cut every group and make it into a variable. for example: user has entered: john@gmail.com, in return he will get a message: echo ' hello john, your host is: @gmail, and the ending is: .com (everything as a variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
$check = $_POST['theemail'];
if (preg_match("/^([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*)@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*)(\.([a-z]{2,3}))$/", $check, $match)){ 
echo 'Hello ' . $match[1] . ' your email address domain is '. $match[3] . '.' . $match[6];
} else {
echo 'Error, you entered an invalid email address';
}
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off"> 
<p align="right">Email <BR><input type="text" name="theemail" size="20" /></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" /></p>
<p align="right"><a href="index.php">register</a></p>
</form>
```

This would output:

> Hello john your email address domain is doe.com

or, if the email address was invalid:

> Error, you entered an invalid email address

And in all cases, it will show the form again.

Comment: But that's not what I am trying to do... john@gmail.com is only an example, the email address could be any adress(see what $check means in my original code) , but what I need to get out of it is a few details; the host, the name before the "@" and the ending (.com etc)

Comment: I think this does what you ask? I added parentheses to the regex to create some extra groups that the engine will give back, added a third parameter to preg_match and showed that all the groups from the email address are given back separately. You can easily do this trick with any regex, even if you know little about them.

Comment: But you did it specifically to "John@gmail.com", Which is not the point. Every email that has been submitted in the form should be tear apart and then divided into 2 groups : What the user has entered before the "@", Let's say its "james", and what the user has entered after the "@". Btw the system will first check if the email is valid and only then will seperate his content into groups. And please don't suggest to explode the "@", because later on i am planning on doing something more complicated with these groups and therefore I need to learn it. thanks for your help btw!

Comment: I changed it to make it look more like your script after your edits.